# Terminate a Pod when container dies

Tags: kubernetes

I want to terminate a Pod when container dies but I did not find an efficient way of doing it.

I can kill the Pod using `kubectl` but I want Pod should get killed/restart automatically whenever any container restarts in a Pod.

Can this task be achieved using operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way, you have to add `livenessProbe` configuration with `restartPolicy` `never` in your pod config.

1. The livenessProbe listen to container failures
2. When the container dies, as `restartPolicy` is never, pod status becomes `Failed`.

For example;

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-http
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - args:
    - /server
    image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        # when "host" is not defined, "PodIP" will be used
        # host: my-host
        # when "scheme" is not defined, "HTTP" scheme will be used. Only "HTTP" and "HTTPS" are allowed
        # scheme: HTTPS
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        httpHeaders:
        - name: X-Custom-Header
          value: Awesome
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: liveness
```

Here's the reference; https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase

Comment: I tried and livenessprobe worked. If container dies because of any reason then pod phase changes to error state.  How do I rescheduled or restart failed pod?    Also, the above method will not work if there are 2 containers in a pod and one dies but other remains running.

Comment: @drifter Glad it worked. You can’t have both `never` and `OnFailure` restartingPolicy settings in one pod — you have to pick one. In this situation, It’s not a great idea to run two containers in the pod. Because you can't fail fast. The question was not asked about multi containers. Please accept the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not critical to terminate a pod immediately when one of the containers fails, you can think about setting a global timeout for the entire pod. This can be achieved by setting `activeDeadlineSeconds` as specified here for the v.1.17: https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#pod-v1-core